# Is it possible to auto-squelch opponents?

Tags: hearthstone

I know that you can squelch your opponent when you first meet them but is there any way that you can set the game up to auto-squelch?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, there is no such thing built-in Hearthstone itself, and the Blizzard team is somewhat against the idea: ([source](http://www.hearthpwn.com/blue-tracker/topic/14049-i-am-out-of-this-toxic-game-thanks-for-nothing-blizz))

> Auto-squelch is something that's been discussed by the Hearthstone
>   team before, but it's not something we're comfortable with. What would
>   likely happen were auto-squelch implemented is that players would
>   enable it after a single incident, and that would be it. They would
>   never reactivate emotes, and as more players did it over time, emotes
>   would largely be devalued.
>
> Squelch exists as it does now as a means to ignore someone being
>   particularly vocal. If someone is just spamming 'thanks' over and
>   over, you have a means to deal with it, and bypass perceived rude
>   behavior. You absolutely have the option to squelch every single
>   opponent you play, and we're comfortable with that. We simply don't
>   want to give players the option to forever disable emotes with the
>   click of a single button.
>
> There's a lot of feedback on this particular issue, and it's something
>   we're constantly evaluating, but that's where we are as a team,
>   presently.

There are however some third-party plugins that do this. For example [this one](https://github.com/ko-vasilev/hearthstone-autosquelch). However, this is against the ToS of Blizzard, because what this does is click the Squelch button automatically. You cannot do that with [pen and paper](https://twitter.com/bdbrode/status/511151446038179840).

Comment: So they are afraid people playing their game would achieve exactly what they want. Blizzard has really become disappointing over the years.

Comment: Next question: Why does Blizzard care so much about emotes being devalued?  What value do they really have currently?

Comment: I can't look into their heads, but probably *they* like some communication between players

Comment: *"However, this is against the ToS [...] You cannot do that with [pen and paper.](https://twitter.com/bdbrode/status/511151446038179840)"* The link you provided reads *"any app that duplicates what you can do with a pencil and paper already is fine."* That does ***not*** mean that an app doing something you *cannot* do with pen and paper is not allowed. (It still might be not allowed in ToS, it's just that the link you provided does not imply this.)

Answer (score -2):

There is a third party software for automatic squelching your opponent - http://altrixsoft.com/en/autosquelch/